# How do I use "filter" in Elasticsearch query with python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

**Here is my code:**

```
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print(res.content)

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

es.search(index="sw", body={"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match":{'skin_color':'fair'}"filter":{'height':'170'}}}}})
```

**AND MY OUTPUT ERROR:**

> File "", line 1
>       es.search(index="sw", body={"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match":{'skin_color':'fair'}"filter":{'height':'170'}}}}})
>                                                                                                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is a syntax error

please check this

```
 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'your_host', 'port': 9200}])

q = {"filter": 
        {"term": 
            {"job desc": "Data Analyst"}
        },
     "_source": {
            "include": ['job place']
        }
    }
# Assume you want "Data Analyst" in the "job desc" field

result = es.search(index='my_index', doc_type='job_list', body=q)
```

This will work here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try it:
because i check your query in "Kibana Dev Tools" and it say you are not allowed use "filter" in  "must" partition.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "skin_color": "fair"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {'height':'170}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_filters.html). Based on this I suspect your query should be:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match": {
                "skin_color": "fair"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
               "match": {
                   "height": "170"
               }
          }
      }
   }
}
```